# MYSQL- join couple of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a couple of tables Employee and Organization. I need a query which can fetch data even Organization has no any Employee. In addition, I want to descend sort with Organization names. Here is my code:

```
select count(*) as count,dept.NAME 
from ORGANIZATION AS dept
left join EMPLOYEE AS emp on emp.DEPT_ID = dept.ID 
group by dept.NAME
ORDER BY count DESC, dept.Name ASC
```

The most crucial matter is not showing Organization with zero employees. Any suggestion?

**EDITED**
Here is my expection:

```
132 Product 
129 Engineering 
127 Legal 
126 Sales 
123 Recruitment 
122 Finance 
122 Research&Development 
119 Operations 
1 Human Resources 
1 Marketing 
0 CTO
```

btw , I got this :

```
132 Product 
129 Engineering 
127 Legal 
126 Sales 
123 Recruitment 
122 Finance 
122 Research&Development 
119 Operations 
1 Human Resources 
1 Marketing
```

Comment: PLease add some sample data and expected result

Comment: @Jens I added my expectation.

Comment: @FarzanNajipour How the source data looks like

Comment: I don't see how you get these results as `emp.DEPT_ID = null` should always be false, so you should get no results at all. Correct is `emp.DEPT_ID IS null`

Comment: If cto existed in organisation you would get a count of at least 1 for cto using your query if you don't then cto does not exist in organisation. BTW your count should be count(emp.dept_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a `LEFT JOIN` and you want to get the `COUNT` of items in the `JOIN`ed table, you need to `COUNT` a field in the `JOIN`ed table, otherwise you will get incorrect results. Changing your query to this should fix the problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(emp.DEPT_ID) AS `count`, dept.NAME 
FROM ORGANIZATION AS dept
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS emp ON emp.DEPT_ID = dept.ID 
GROUP BY dept.NAME
ORDER BY `count` DESC, dept.NAME ASC
```

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the  use of left join is correct
(this is the join that retrive rows  also if the relation don't match)
but when you use left join don't use a where condition for rows involved  in left join otherwise these work as an inner join

```
select count(*) as count,dept.NAME 
from ORGANIZATION AS dept
left join EMPLOYEE AS emp on emp.DEPT_ID = dept.ID 
group by dept.NAME
ORDER BY count DESC, dept.Name ASC
```